scala compiler complains about given CanEqual being unused but it is
In our project, we are using strict equality (-language:strictEquality), so when I have a type alias like the following I also have to define a CanEqual explicitly
object Foo {
  type A = Double | String
  given canEqualAA: CanEqual[A, A] = CanEqual.derived
}

The problem is that wherever I need to compare instances of it, like for example
import Foo.given // warning: unused import

val a: Foo.A = 42;
val b: Foo.A = "hello"

a == b


the compiler complains about it being an unused import (no matter if I import it as Foo.given or Foo.canEqualAA, or even if I define it inline instead of importing it). In contrast, if I remove the import it can't compile because the two can't be compared.
Why isn't the compiler seeing that such a given is being used, and how do I solve this situation?

Would you be able to provide a minimal reproducible example and maybe open an issue in Scala's GitHub repo?

@GaëlJ I edited my question to add more details since the problem arises when the type is wrapped in a functor. Here there is also a Scastie snippet where you can see the warning https://scastie.scala-lang.org/r5cfDw1QRZqGJyeC21GNdA

I'd report a bug: this is check for unused implicit/given, but it's the compiler's strict equality check that verifies it rather than typechecking the method signature, so it would have to be manually added to some list of exceptions during unused analysis. Perhaps "given used by another given" missed that special "checked only by strict equality" casing and it needs to be reported.

I did further experiments and found out I was wrong when I said that the problem is related to the type being wrapped in a functor. I opened this issue, thank you for the advice
